# Chrome Workspace source auto complete not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autocomplete, google-chrome-devtools

I've created a silly html page and added `Rxjs` and `Rx-Dom` JavaScript files. I've added an `app.js` file to write my code. I'm running a simple web server to serve the files. I've added my local folder as a `Workspace` folder in `Chrome`. Now whenever I write some code in the `Chrome` console I'm getting the `autocomplete`, but whenever I'm switching to source and try to write something in the source file, I'm not getting any `autocomplete`. As to what I'm saying related to the picture, writing anything in the `app.js` file I'm not not getting `autocomplete`. Is there something I'm missing.

OS - Windows 10 (Build 10586.71)

Chrome - Version 48.0.2564.82

[image: Chrome]

Comment: It is not implemented in the DevTools Workspace to my knowledge. You should consider filing a bug at crbug.com if you want this feature.

Comment: It looks strange. Could you provide archive with files for testing?

Comment: @AlexeyKozyatinskiy I don't understand what you mean by archive. But files [rx.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js) and [rx.dom.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs-dom/7.0.3/rx.dom.js) are available via the links.

Comment: What do you mean by "no autocomplete"? There should be a basic one in the Sources panel, which suggest already typed words. The Console autocomplete is more clever, it analyzes runtime environment and suggests actual properties accessible on the object.

Comment: Meaning that the `window` and `document` objects are also not showing in `autocomplete`. Also, if I have other libraries loaded, then will they show in the source `autocomplete`?

Comment: window and document will not show in the autocomplete - the autocomlpete in sources panel is pretty dumb. It will show you only words you've already typed in the edited file. Actually, the autocomplete system in Sources Panel  doesn't even know that you're editing JavaScript.

Comment: Aww snap. I was thinking it is as smart as the Console autocomplete. What should I do with the question. Can you please post the same as answer, then I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although both Console and Sources panels have autocomplete functionality, they work quite differently.

The autocomlpete in Sources panel is pretty dumb. It will show you only words you've already typed in the edited file. Actually, the autocomplete system in Sources Panel doesn't even know that you're editing JavaScript.

The autocomplete in Console is way more clever - it suggests autocompletion values based on the runtime inspection.

This way, you see "document" and "window" in the console autocomplete, and you usually don't have them in the "Sources" autocomplete.

Comment: This is not much anything new other than what @Andrey said.

Comment: Exactly, I've just summed up our comment discussion into an answer.

Comment: Hope that somebody from the chrome team is watching this.